# Integrating 3rd party Android JAR into Titanium Mobile app?

Tags: android, mobile, jar, android-intent, titanium

I'm writing a Titanium app trying to play YouTube videos.  The goal is to keep the user inside the app, so **calling the native youtube app, which I can do already, is out of the question.**  I have code that works on iOS, but only because embedding in the webView supports the content.  That's not the case for Android, unfortunately.

It seems like http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/wiki/OpenYouTubePlayerActiviyInstructions will solve my problems, but I'm not sure how to utilize it from Titanium.  The doc suggests doing this from Android:

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytpl://"+YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID), this, OpenYouTubeActivity.class);//public Intent (String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) from Android doc
startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

So, utilizing http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Android.Intent-object.html and http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Android.Activity-object.html as guides, came up with:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
            action: 'null',
            data: 'ytv://'+vguid,
            packageName: 'com.keyes.youtube',
            className: 'com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubeActivity'
        });
        Ti.Android.Activity.startActivity(intent);
```

In my TiApp.XML, I've added this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission> 
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> 
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
        <activity android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"></activity>
    </android>
```

When I try to run the code, I'm getting this error:
TypeError:  Cannot call method "startActivity" of undefined(file:///android_asset/Resources/app.js#162)
where 162 is the line number of startActivity(intent);

I think it has something to do with the source not being on the classpath (I've tried using just his .jar as well as the separate .java files) and/or it not being used as a module.  I've utilized ONE iOS module, but have no idea how to write my own Android one, let alone port someone's code to a module.

Any help?  I'm sure this is something a lot of Titanium users battle with.

*edit 1*

I've gotten some progress on this, still no solution.  I've gone the 'module' route because I haven't seen another way to get the jars/java files included in the project build.  I built the module as "ytModule", and got it included by adding

```
<module version="0.1">com.keyes.ytModule</module>
```

to tiapp.xml.  I then get

```
[DEBUG] Looking for Titanium Module id: com.keyes.ytModule, version: 0.1, platform: <any platform>
[DEBUG] module_id = com.keyes.ytModule
[DEBUG] appending module: com.keyes.ytModule.YtplayerModule
```

when I build from TitaniumStudio.  I'm working on this and will keep posting updates/trying suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the new SDK.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android/module_sdk

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> The reason is its not able to call the Activity's method which is
> ```
>
> throwing this error.

```
 Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent)
```

This should work.

Comment: That's a start, but now Titanium thinks I haven't declared the activity in my tiapp.xml.  I'm almost positive this is because the java files aren't on the classpath when it builds the APK.  How do I add them?  I don't think I should need a module for this, but I don't know how else I can get the packages on the path.

Comment: In your Titanium SDK find this $version/android/modules and inside modules add the jar and re compile the App.